# Why does AttributedString work with Strings but not labelWithAttributedString?

Tags: swift, macos

I have some AttributedKeys assigned to a String object and the same Keys attributed to a label that was instantiated with labelWithAttributedString - many attributes translate to both objects, but the ParagraphStyle ones do not carry over to the label - I've looked in the docs but can't seem to understand why - I'm posting some Playground code to show

```
var fontHeight:CGFloat = 36.0
var baseFont = NSFont(name: "Raleway", size: fontHeight)
var fontColor = NSColor.blue
var myParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
myParagraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
myParagraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = fontHeight

var backgroundColor = NSColor.red
var attributeDictionary = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: baseFont,           NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: fontColor, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: backgroundColor, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: myParagraphStyle]
var myString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello there as if you didn't know, this is a long text string", attributes: attributeDictionary)


var myLabel2 =  NSTextField(labelWithAttributedString: myString)
```

[image: Playground showing results...]

The paragraph behavior (line height and the trailing ellipsis) show in the String but not the label.

Comment: The label is scaled. Add `myLabel2.frame.size.width = 500` `let myLabel3 = myLabel2`

Comment: Thanks Willeke - I added the lines and it worked - I quite don't yet understand why I need to create a new label and copy it from label2 - ie your last line...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Playgrounds, how can I redisplay the label after setting the width?

Comment: The screenshot I have in the original post is from Playground - after each statement you can view the result in real-time - this is for trying and debugging in real-time

Comment: The result of setting the width is an image of the width, not the view. I did `let myLabel3 = myLabel2` to redisplay the view after changing the width.